# Make two functions work at the same time python pyrogram?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, pyrogram

Through asyncio, I don’t understand how to write, but through the Thread thread it displays an error:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (flud)'.
raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2 (flud_to_phantom)
```

There are two view functions (they are almost the same, so I will write only one):

```
def flud(accou....):
    member_n = 0
    while True:
        app = Client(name=....)
        text = choice(messages)

        async def in_flud():
            async with app:
                await app.send_message(chat_id=chat.id, text=text)
                await app.stop()
        app.run(in_flud())
        sleep(delay)

def flud_1(accou....):
    member_n = 0
    while True:
        app = Client(name=....)
        text = choice(messages)

        async def in_flud_1():
            async with app:
                await app.send_message(chat_id=chat.id, text=text)
                await app.stop()
        app.run(in_flud())
        sleep(delay)

Thread(target=flud, args=(ac...)).start()
Thread(target=flud_1, args=(sad...)).start()
```

How can I make them work at the same time?

Comment: You’re probably looking for asyncio.gather.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read the description of tags before using it. The python-telegram-bot tag is not a general tag about telegram bots written in python

Comment: It seems like the whole point of the program is to execute the line `await app.send_message(...)`.  This will REQUIRE the use of asyncio.  Use of threads is NOT REQUIRED and probably doesn't help you at all.  Your first sentence was "Through asyncio, I don’t understand how to write."  So you've pinpointed the exact problem: you need to write an asyncio program and you don't know how.  I suggest a web search for "python asyncio ebook." Select and read one of several fine books on the subject.  Get back to us if there is something you don't understand.  The community will be happy to help.